# Access variables/functions of instantiating class

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write code which matches what is happening physically. I writing code which accesses a physical chassis which has two hardware devices in it. Right now I have a chassis class which I want to have chassis level variables and functions (Hostname, port, readVariable, ...). I also have device level classes which have device specific functions but need access to information from the chassis level class.

Right now that looks something like this pseudo code:

```
class Chassis {
  public:
    Chassis():

    String hostname;
    int port;
    Dev1 device1;
    Dev2 device2;

    int readVar(String varName, String *result);
    int writeVar(String varName, String varVal);
}

class Dev1 {
  public:
    Dev1();
    int updateStatusVars();
}

Dev1::Dev1() {
}

int Dev1::updateStatusVars() {
  int status = Chassis::readVar("Var1",var1Val);
  return status;
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this? I want the main class to only have one instance of the chassis which in turn holds the references to the devices. Inheritance doesn't really solve this since I would have to have two devices each of which inherit from chassis. Each of those devices could have different hostnames and ports. I don't want that. It's the situation I'm specifically trying to avoid. I want have a single reference to hostname and port accessible by each device and certain functions which the devices can access also.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: 1) This `Dev1() {` should be `Dev1::Dev1() {`. 2) `Chassis::readVar("Var1",var1Val);` You can't because  `readVar()` is not static.

Comment: In these cases I usually add a `Chassis *chassis` member variable to `Dev1` and `Dev2` and write `:device1(this), device2(this)` in the constructor.

Comment: You may (1) use a `Chassis` *singleton* or (2) pass a `Chassis` reference as an argument to a `Dev` constructor and store it there or (3) pass a `Chassis` reference to all `Dev` methods that need it.

Comment: The chassis doesn't hold *references* to the devices, it holds *values* that *are* devices

Answer (score 0):

Chassis doesn't know about the specific hardware installed in it, instead it defines interfaces for I/O.  The devices also exist as separate entities that may or may not be plugged into the Chassis.  I would model it like so (pseudocode)...

```
class PCIInterface
{
public:
    PCIInterface(){}
    virtual ~PCIInterface(){}
    virtual void Update()=0;
    virtual int ReadVar ( String varName, String *result )=0;
    virtual int WriteVar( String varName, String value )=0;
};

class Device : public PCIInterface
{
public:
    Device(){}
    virtual ~Device(){}

    void Powerup( PCIInterface *chassis );

    /* PCIInterface */
    virtual void Update();
    virtual int ReadVar( String varName, String *result );
    virtual int WriteVar( String varName, String value );

protected:
    PCIInterface *m_chassis;
}

void Device::Powerup( PCIInterface *chassis )
{
m_chassis = chassis;
}

class Chassis : public PCIInterface
{
public:
    Chassis(){ m_slots.resize( MAX_SLOTS ); }
    virtual ~Chassis(){}

    void PlugIn( const int slot_id, Device *device );

    /* PCIInterface */
    virtual void Update();
    virtual int ReadVar( String varName, String *result );
    virtual int WriteVar( String varName, String value );

protected:
    std::vector<PCIInterface*> m_slots;
}

void Chassis::PlugIn( const int slot_id, Device *device )
{
assert( slot_id < m_slots.size() );
m_slots[ slot_id ] = device;
device->PowerUp( this );
}

void Chassis::Update()
{
for( auto device : m_slots )
    {
    if( *device ) device->Update();
    }
}

class DeviceFlower : public Device
{
...
}

void DeviceFlower::Update()
{
String str;
m_chassis->ReadVar( "ChassisName", &str );
cout << str;
}

class DeviceRock : public Device
{
...
}

void main()
{
auto the_chassis = Chassis();
auto first_device = DeviceFlower();
auto second_device = DeviceRock();

the_chassis.PlugIn( 0, &first_device );
the_chassis.PlugIn( 1, &second_device );

while( true )
    {
    the_chassis.Update();
    }

}
```